# How to remove "LF" from column in PySpark?

Tags: regex, apache-spark, pyspark, replace, special-characters

I have a problem with my PySpark script in AWS Glue.

Basically I have this CSV file from S3 that I put into Redshift. I noticed after some records that the value of column was off, and after some digging I discovered that the file had a *line feed* at a certain point (in Notepad++ the special character was **LF** when the line breaks).

With that in mind I implemented this piece to my script in order to remove the special character:

```
## converting DynamicFrame to Data Frame
dataframe_remove_chars = ApplyMapping_node1647881653734.toDF()

## columns to which replace the carriage return
columns_to_replace = ['main_ph_num']

## regexp to remove character in all records for a column
for i in columns_to_replace:
    dataframe_remove_chars = dataframe_remove_chars.withColumn(i,regexp_replace(i, '\r', ''))

## converting back to DynamicFrame
ApplyMapping_node1647881653734 = DynamicFrame.fromDF(dataframe_remove_chars, glueContext, "ApplyMapping_node1647881653734")
```

This doesn't seem to work because I know the file is supposed to have 1000 records, but in Redshift I keep getting more records.

I think I'm writing the reg_exp wrong but I've looked a lot of posts and all point to this method.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Just use `multiLine` while reading your csv file. Essentially, while reading the csv into your dataframe as `df = spark.read.format("csv").option("multiLine", "true").option("header", "true").load(<Your CSV Path>)`

Comment: @DKNY I'm using the data catalog in Glue to load the file, like this:
```AWSGlueDataCatalog_node1647881643527 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(
    database="s3-sat-dth-dev",
    table_name="s_org_ext",
    transformation_ctx="AWSGlueDataCatalog_node1647881643527",
)```

I don't recall having that option.

Comment: LF is `\n`, so try `regexp_replace(i, '[\r\n]+', '')`